# Why does "!=" if operator not work when comparing a float to 0 in Python

Tags: python, compare

I want to create a programm to analyse mathematical functions. I use the float datatype for my parameters and need to compare them, wether they are zero or not. I use this code tiles for it:

```
a=input("a=")
a=float(a)
```

```
if a !=0:
   a=leitko
```

The variable "leitko" is not defined earlier in the code and my intention is that, if "a" is not 0, "leitko" shouold get the same value as "a". The problem is, the comparison is not working. Can somebody help me?

Comment: btw Did you mean: `leitko = a`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]: What is the input, what do you expect to happen, what happens instead? Note that unlike what the description claims, the code assigns ``leitko`` to ``a``, not the other way around.

Comment: Is there an error you're getting?
Also, to make `leitko" shouold get the same value as "a"`, you should define `leitko = a`

Comment: Python reads from right to left. The value to be assigned should always be on its left. In your case ```a=leitko``` is wring. It should be ```leitko=a```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your variable assignements the wrong way around, you must write `variable = value` in python to give a variable a value.

So in your case, `leitiko=a` to create a new variable named `leitiko` and containing the same thing as `a`.

When you write `a=leitiko`, python is trying to give the variable `a` the same value as a variable name `leitiko`. But that `leitiko` variable doesn't exist, so it gives you an error.